# Session Undefined - Using Connect-Redis / ExpressJS / Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis

This morning I awoke to find Nodejitsu spinning out the following error:

`Warning: connection.session() MemoryStore is not designed for a production environment, as it will leak memory, and will not scale past a single process.`

'Well then!' I thought to myself - and off I went to find something more suitable. I settled on Redis, and immediately began implementing `connect-redis` and `node-redis` into my application.

However, the following error continues to surface after repeated attempts at a fix. The error is as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'loggedIn' of undefined
        at /Users/Ryan/Aggregus/server.js:300:25
        at Promise.<anonymous> (/Users/Ryan/Aggregus/object_models/user.js:60:5)
        at Promise.<anonymous> (/Users/Ryan/Aggregus/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:162:8)
        at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
        at Promise.emit (/Users/Ryan/Aggregus/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:79:38)
        at Promise.fulfill (/Users/Ryan/Aggregus/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:92:20)
        at /Users/Ryan/Aggregus/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1813:13
        at model.Document.init (/Users/Ryan/Aggregus/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:243:11)
        at completeOne (/Users/Ryan/Aggregus/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1811:10)
        at /Users/Ryan/Aggregus/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1779:11
```

`loggedIn` is simply referring to `req.session.loggedIn`, a session variable I use to track logged-in users. The following is the application code in question:

```
var express = require('express');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var request = require('request');
var underscore = require('underscore');
var mandrill = require('node-mandrill')('0bFNPDenlDiZtu7aXujDQQ');
var connect = require('connect');
var engines = require('consolidate');
var fs = require('fs');
var redis = require("redis").createClient();

var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);

var sessionStore = new RedisStore({
    client: redis
});

var stripe_api_key = 'KEY';
var Stripe = require('stripe')(stripe_api_key);

var app = express(); 

app.configure(function() {
    app.engine('html', engines.jade);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.use(express.cookieParser()); 
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.session({secret: "svtabyrki4q786as37c785ta8vi56aiw4i8w467acv", store: sessionStore}));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));
    app.use(express.compress()); 
    app.use(app.router);

});

// Mongoose Connection

var db = mongoose.connection;

var dbURI = 'HIDDENURL';

db.on('disconnected', function() {
    mongoose.connect(dbURI, {server:{auto_reconnect:true}});
});

db.on('error', function(error) {
  console.error('Error in MongoDb connection: ' + error);
  mongoose.disconnect();
});

mongoose.connect(dbURI, {server:{auto_reconnect:true}});

// Mongoose Object Models

var User = require('./object_models/user')(mongoose, nodemailer, mandrill);
var Notifications = require('./object_models/notification')(mongoose, nodemailer);
var Experience = require('./object_models/experience')(mongoose, nodemailer);
var Booking = require('./object_models/booking')(mongoose, nodemailer);
var Review = require('./object_models/review')(mongoose, nodemailer);
var Heart = require('./object_models/heart')(mongoose, nodemailer);
var Message = require('./object_models/message')(mongoose, nodemailer);

// Nodemailer Settings

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "ryan@aggregus.com",
        pass: pwd
    }
});

// Bootstrap Call

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('../index.html');
    console.log("WUSUP");
});
```

To provide further clarity, here is what I have tried up until this point to no avail:

1. I have placed `app.use(express.cookieParser());` prior to the `express.session` call, as most articles of this subject suggested.
2. I have ensured that my `new RedisStore` call references the `client` directly upon initialization.
3. I have placed `app.use(app.router)` after both the init calls for both `express.session` and 'express.cookieParser'.
4. My Redis server is fully functional, via the `createClient()` call.

This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714999/nodejs-express-redisstore-req-session-undefined) was resolved by preventing a rather insignificant `app.use` initialization to call `app.router` prior to Express' sessionStore being initialized.

Thus, TL;DR: In using `connect-redis`, my session variables return `undefined`. I have scoured the web for answers, and my only clue would be that `app.router` is being started prior to Express' own session handling. Where that little glitch occurs is beyond me. Gods of Stack Overflow have mercy on my poor soul.

Edit: Thought a package.json might be handy for reference. Generated via NodeJitsu:

```
{
  "name": "Aggregus",
  "subdomain": "aggregus-Aggregus",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "version": "0.0.0-14",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "connect": "2.7.8",
    "consolidate": "0.9.1",
    "express": "3.2.2",
    "jade": "0.30.0",
    "mongoose": "3.6.9",
    "node-mandrill":"1.0.1",
    "nodemailer": "0.4.1",
    "request":"2.22.0",
    "stripe": "1.3.0",
    "underscore":"1.4.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're calling connect-redis wrong, and you don't need redis installed separately. However, I don't see connect-redis in your package.json, so you should `npm install --save connect-redis`. Then do something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
var ports = require('./classes/ports.js');
var config = require('./config/config.js');
var routes = require('./routes');
var errors = require('./classes/errors.js');

var app = express();
ports(app);
app
.use(express.logger())
.use(express.compress())
.use(express.cookieParser())
.use(express.session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    port: config.redisPort,
    host: config.redisHost,
    db: config.redisDatabase,
    pass: config.redisPassword
  }),
  secret: 'Your secret here',
  proxy: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))
.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/../public/img/favicon.ico'))
.use(express.bodyParser())
.use(express.methodOverride())

routes(app);
errors(app);
```

Comment: Hey @dankohn how do I set a function to immediately set req.user from the cookie before passing on any requests?

Comment: You almost certainly want to be using passport or everyauth. Here's an example of setting a cookie, which you could do near the top: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484649/csrf-token-not-working-when-submitting-form-in-express/20485620#20485620

Comment: one question should this part be implemented in master loop or else case of the cluster check