# Running multiple socket.io servers and connecting to them from one express website

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, express, session-store

I need to make system what is used on page: https://www.csgohunt.com/

They have 3 socket.io servers running on: *ws.csgohunt.com, chat.csgohunt.com, csgohunt.com*

First two seems to be running on different http server, but when you connect to all 3 sockets from website *csgohunt.com* (You can see it from network tab), then all 3 sockets communictating.

**Whats more interesting** is, that even those 2 sockets what **runs on different http server share express session** and they know when user is logged and when not.

I have working Express + Socket.IO + Passport app where session sharing works fine when you connect to socket server **running on same http server as express**. But when I start nsecond socket server on different http server (but same app) and using same sessionStore, second server not see sessions.

Whats the best way to achieve this kind of system? I don't want to have 1 socket server for everything.

EDIT: I found that they using Heroku. Is this giving them possibility to do what I described? I have absolutely no expirience with it.

Comment: This was absolutely unusefull answer :) They pointing to same Ip because server is hidden behind Cloudflare + You can use proxy to redirect subdomains to different ports

Comment: How do you know they are connected to physically different server processes?  Sharing the same express session across different processes would just require using a centralized data store for the session so that multiple processes could access it.  Same way that express-session works when using clustering.

Comment: I am using mysql express-session middleware. I know it because if you access socket's address in browser you get "Cannot GET" message

Comment: And, do you have each of your express-session instances configured to use the exact same mysql database?

Comment: Yes ;) Same database. I even tried to use same instance of sessionStore and passport. Nothing works.

Comment: Cannot GET just means the server returned a 404 (which is what you see when you look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger) when you go to http://chat.csgohunt.com in the browser.  It doesn't necessarily mean it's a different server process.  One could have a server process that examines the incoming host name and only allows socket.io connections, sending a 404 to everything else.  But, the same server process serves web pages if the host is cgohunt.com.  Who knows.

Comment: But how run multiple socket.io servers in one process :D

Comment: Why would you want or need to run multiple socket.io servers in one process?  Socket.io has namespaces if you want to separate some connections from others.  If you want multiple socket.io servers in the same process, you would probably need to run them on separate ports and then configure to allow cross origin requests or to force webSocket as the transport (to avoid CORS issues).

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to share sessions among multiple server processes (since that's what any clustering implementation would likely want to do), but I'm not sure myself how to configure that.  I just don't quite understand why you even need to do that.

Comment: So why devs of csgohunt splitted socketio servers to different subdomains if there is way to split socket.io server to different namespaces? I think its because if any of three socket servers crash, remaining servers will run

Comment: There is no need to use separate subdomains to have redundancy if one server crashes.  That's what clustering-type solutions are for.  I don't know why they used subdomains.  Plus your idea of putting multiple servers in the same process wouldn't provide crash redundancy.  Rather than just copy someone else's implementation, I'd suggest you come up with your own requirements and find your own design that meets those requirements.  We can't tell you why someone else chose a particular design.  You need to tell us what YOUR requirements are.

Comment: I want same thing what they have: Multiple socket.io servers and redundancy. What I need for this if we forgot about how csgohunt did this

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [nodejs clustering and express-sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626279/nodejs-clustering-and-expressjs-sessions) and [express-mysql-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session).