# CSRF token not working when submitting form in express

Tags: node.js, express

i'm trying to get forms working in my express app.  i have a middleware function that passes the csrf token, req.session._csrf, to res.locals.csrf_token, so the view can use it.  now i'm trying to use the local variable in my view and i'm getting a forbidden error from my session middleware.

here's my form code - i'm using handlebars as my templating engine:

```
  <form method='post' action='/api/entries' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
    <input type='hidden' name='_csrf' value={{csrf_token}} />
    <input class='foo' type='text' />
    <input class='bar' type='text' />
    <button id='submit' type='submit'> SUBMIT
  </form>
```

i've tried referencing the csrf_token variable with and without the double curly braces and neither works.  any ideas on what i am doing wrong?  the Error: Forbidden happens before my route function for POSTing to /api/entries is even called.  so i'm pretty sure the problem is that i'm doing something wrong with referencing the csrf token..

**edit:**in regards to the "req.session._csrf is deprecated, use req.csrfToken() instead" getting logged to the console, i did:

```
grep -r '_csrf' .
```

in my app directory.  here was the output.. it doesn't look like i'm referencing it anywhere besides the view, where my hidden CSRF field is named "_csrf"..

```
./node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:    var secret = req.session._csrfSecret;
./node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:      req.session._csrfSecret = secret;
./node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:      Object.defineProperty(req.session, '_csrf', {
./node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:          console.warn('req.session._csrf is deprecated, use req.csrfToken() instead');
./node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:  return (req.body && req.body._csrf)
./node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:    || (req.query && req.query._csrf)
./v/home.hbs:    <input type='hidden' name='_csrf' value={{csrf_token}} />
./v/show.hbs:  <input type='hidden'  name='_csrf' value={{csrf_token}} />
```

here is the entire error stack i'm getting when trying to POST to the /api/entries endpoint (i stupidly neglected to mention this before, but i'm using connect-redis for session middleware):

```
Error: Forbidden
    at Object.exports.error (appFolder/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:63:13)
    at createToken (appFolder/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:82:55)
    at Object.handle (appFolder/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:48:24)
    at next (appFolder/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at next (appFolder/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:318:9)
    at appFolder/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:342:9
    at appFolder/node_modules/connect-redis/lib/connect-redis.js:101:14
    at try_callback (appFolder/node_modules/redis/index.js:580:9)
    at RedisClient.return_reply (appFolder/node_modules/redis/index.js:670:13)
    at ReplyParser.<anonymous> (appFolder/node_modules/redis/index.js:312:14)
```

**edit 2:** the error in connect-redis.js is a function trying to get the current session by the session ID and failing.  don't know why this would be happening, my connect-redis setup looks correct.  this is killing me

Comment: How are you rendering the template? You're passing the value `csrf_token`?

Comment: i have a function in my express configuration that looks like:  app.use(function(req, res, next) { res.locals.csrf_token = req.session._csrf; next(); })

Comment: i tried explicitly adding it to the locals object included in res.render() and that didn't work either

Comment: What's the `render` parameters? `{ csrf_token: xyz }`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSRF syntax has changed slightly in the latest versions of Express/Connect. You now want your middleware to look like this:

```
.use(express.csrf())
.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
  res.locals.csrftoken = req.csrfToken();
  next();
})
```

For testing your code, note that you first need to GET the form page in order to generate the CSRF token. Only then will your POST succeed. If it fails, you need to reload the page in the browser before trying to POST again.

Comment: implemented it that way, now i'm getting a TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'csrfToken' when i try to GET the page with the form

Comment: also i'm on express 3.3.4

Comment: Please upgrade to 3.4.6 and try again.

Comment: after upgrading, i'm getting "Error: Forbidden at Object.exports.error (myHomeFolder/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:63:13) at createToken.  i also get a message in the console: "req.session._csrf is deprecated, use req.csrfToken() instead".  my code is identical to your example

Comment: You must still have "_csrf" somewhere. Try searching for it in your code. Also try deleting your whole node_modules and reinstalling with npm install.

Comment: yeah, this is baffling me cause i saw that and thought i had _csrf referenced somewhere too, so i searched for it.  didn't find it anywhere in my app.  after removing my node_modules and reinstalling everything i'm still getting the same error.  even weirder, to debug, i'm referencing my local "csrf_token" variable in a h1 in the view and it shows up!  but when i try to submit the form it gives that same error...thank you for all your help btw..

Comment: attached additional information to my post.  i'm also using connect-redis for session storage, which i think is causing the error..don't know why i didn't mention that before...

Comment: You're using the local csrf_token but assigning req.locals.csrftoken without the underscore.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42998/discussion-between-amagumori-and-dankohn)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and trying everything i could.  Have you solved that?

Comment: Also having the same error. Only when I upload files though on a POST. Thinking it's an issue with connect-redis. ANyone resolve this?

Comment: Hey, with this strategy, doesn't this `res.locals.csrftoken = req.csrfToken()` generate a new token every time for every request? Is it okay if we just generate one for the life of the session? What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: @MattKim are you running into the 403 forbidden issue? It's happening to me on one page only for the weirdest reason...

Comment: @bob_cobb No I'm not...it works but I just don't want to generate a new token on every request. This generates a token on all get requests too. If you show me the code I can try to take a look.

Comment: Doesn't `req.csrfToken()` generate new one each time? You seem to call that twice.. use a variable instead

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**: If you don't need file uploads, don't use the `multipart/form-data` enctype. Switching to the default enctype would allow `express.csrf()` to parse the `_csrf` token.

In order to parse forms with the `multipart/form-data` enctype, you need use a multipart parser in your app configuration, or handle file uploads yourself. It's recommended to avoid using the included `express.bodyParser()` and instead use something like `busboy` or `formidable` on the routes you're expecting file uploads, to prevent an [exploit](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1673).

If you go this route, your `_csrf` field will no longer be caught by `express.csrf()` because the form body will not be parsed until after the request passes that middleware. Set your form action to `'/api/entries?_csrf={{csrf_token}}'` to get around this.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var express = require('express');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded())
  .use(express.json())
  .use(express.cookieParser())
  .use(express.session())
  .use(express.csrf())

app.get('/upload', function(req, res) {
  // File uploads ignored.
  res.render('upload', {_csrf:req.csrfToken()});
});

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  // Explicitly handle uploads
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.uploadDir = 'temp';

  var count = 0;
  var maxAllowed = 10;

  form.onPart = function(part) {
    if (!part.filename) return form.handlePart(part);

    count++;

    // Ignore any more files.
    if (count > maxAllowed) return part.resume();

    form.handlePart(part);
  };

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    // Process the files. If you don't need them, delete them.
    // Note that you should still reap your temp directory on occasion.

    async.map(Object.keys(files), function(key, cb) {
      fs.unlink(files[key].path, cb);
    }, function(err) {
      res.end();
    });
   });
});
```

Comment: Setting the form action as written is what fixed the issue for me. However, in rare occasions I noticed that I was still getting the forbidden error. After some investigation I realized I had to encodeURIComponent the csrf value inside the form action.

Answer (score 3):

I too hit this problem today and it's taken several hours for me to find a solution. Hopefully this answer helps someone with my exact problem. As @amagumori, I'm using redis for session handling and express 3.4.8, connect-redis 1.4.7.

Basically I was able to determine that the order of my express configuration affects the number of times a new token was issued. It seemed like everything being served out of public was creating a new token.

Specifically in my case I had to move the calls

```
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

above

```
app.use(express.csrf());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.token = req.csrfToken();
    next();
});
```

and tokens are issued as expected for sessions.

Comment: Thanks! I ran into the same issue using repo hachathon-starter.