# Express.csrf() - token undefined - express 3.5.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, csrf

I am using the `express.csrf()` middleware to generate a token and placing the generated token into a form using `res.locals`; however, the token is `undefined` when the page is rendered.

I have looked at multiple tutorials and SO questions regarding the implementation of this middleware, and it does not seem to work for me.

Here are the relevant `dependencies`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "3.5.1",
    "ejs": "*",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.11",
    "connect-mongo": "^0.4.1"
 }
```

Here is the relevant `app.js` code:

```
app.use(express.session({
    key:'app.sess',
    store: new MongoStore({
        db: "sessionStore"  
    })
}));
//***********************************
app.use(express.csrf());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  res.locals.token = req.session._csrf;
  console.log("Token: " + res.locals.token);
  next();

});
//***********************************
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/register',register.registration);
app.post('/register',register.doRegistration);
```

And here is the relevant portion of the `register.ejs` file:

`<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= token %>">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of search this post answered the problem. Specifically the answer posted by @Ian Wootten.

[CSRF token not working when submitting form in express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484649/csrf-token-not-working-when-submitting-form-in-express)